Unable to boot android emulator with my custom kernel
I did build a custom kernel like this:
mkdir -p ~/dlink-decompile
cd ./dlink-decompile
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git
cd common
git checkout android14-6.1-2024-04_r11


make clean
make mrproper
make ARCH=x86_64 defconfig
make menuconfig
make scripts
make

cd ..

git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus.git
cd rtl8188eus

make -C /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common ARCH=x86_64 KSRC=~/dlink-decompile/common KDIR=~/dlink-decompile/common

Aiming to have the kernel embeded with an rtl8188eus module. Then I made an AVD:
avdmanager create avd -n CustomKernel -k "system-images;android-34;google_apis_playstore;x86_64" -b "x86_64"

And I boot the AVD with the custom kernel:
emulator -avd CustomKernel -kernel /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -qemu -m 2048 -enable-kvm

But emulator fails to boot. Whereas if I ommit the -kernel /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage param, emulator boots fine.
Looking at the path /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage I see:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pcmagas pcmagas 22 Ιουν 19 21:15 /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -> ../../x86/boot/bzImage


And Also file exists ion the symlinked path:
ls -l /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common/arch/x86_64/boot/../../x86/boot/bzImage
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 11513440 Ιουν 19 19:22 /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common/arch/x86_64/boot/../../x86/boot/bzImage

The emulator shows a grey screen:

And after a while, still remains the same. The emulator output upon console is:
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-pcmagas/emu-crash-34.2.14.db, detection is enabled for process: 77641
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.14.0 (build_id 11834374) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/pcmagas/system-images/android-34/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-pcmagas/emu-crash-34.2.14.db, detection is enabled for process: 77641
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_posture_requested(int) ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_posture_selection_dialog() ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_resizable_requested(PresetEmulatorSizeType) ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_resizable_dialog() ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_sleep_timer_done() ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_unfold_timer_done() ((null):0, (null))
library_mode host gpu mode host
INFO    | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoI0620 21:37:23.875587   77641 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
cannot add library libvulkan.so: failed
added library libvulkan.so.1
createGlobalVkEmulation:995 Selecting Vulkan device: AMD Radeon RX 550 Series (RADV POLARIS11)
initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
I0620 21:37:24.082889   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1276] Initializing VkEmulation features:
I0620 21:37:24.082906   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1277]     glInteropSupported: true
I0620 21:37:24.082924   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1278]     useDeferredCommands: true
I0620 21:37:24.082927   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1280]     createResourceWithRequirements: true
I0620 21:37:24.082932   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1281]     useVulkanComposition: false
I0620 21:37:24.082935   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1282]     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
I0620 21:37:24.082939   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1283]     enable guestRenderDoc: false
I0620 21:37:24.082942   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1284]     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
I0620 21:37:24.082960   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1285]     enable ETC2 emulation: true
I0620 21:37:24.082963   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1286]     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
I0620 21:37:24.082983   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1287]     guestUsesAngle: false
I0620 21:37:24.082986   77641 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1288]     useDedicatedAllocations: true
I0620 21:37:24.083206   77641 FrameBuffer.cpp:506] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (AMD)
I0620 21:37:24.083213   77641 FrameBuffer.cpp:507] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (AMD Radeon RX 550 Series (polaris11, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-112-generic))
I0620 21:37:24.083230   77641 FrameBuffer.cpp:508] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2)
I0620 21:37:24.083233   77641 FrameBuffer.cpp:509] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 
I0620 21:37:24.083252   77641 FrameBuffer.cpp:510] Graphics Device Extensions N/A
INFO    | OpenGL Vendor=[Google (AMD)]
INFO    | OpenGL Renderer=[Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (AMD Radeon RX 550 Series (polaris11, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-112-generic))]
INFO    | OpenGL Version=[OpenGL ES 3.0 (4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2)]
INFO    | Enabled VulkanAllocateDeviceMemoryOnly feature for gpu vendor AMD on Linux
INFO    | Sending adb public key [QAAAAA35gig7grg+E7kDJj7JMLZ2lE8gXpjq8HXYB0V7UZHHe8uA9ma9OmwDT09UAb85aArFqRNLiJegREOaV2R/Co4wWRVBInXqCoRRkKEnbqO53SLzdRnyh1z6DYkXFQIfFkd9JqeOD46UItc/ru4SQi5hdY4FSjevalU3u0SIZGu7OdJ+pRAozzvKcfTU7F33cs2FJ0plzVl7Corqhyi53ncpoMRSfkearMDVTxPIKn4QjR1u6xv+oa5N8itlCw+benFmd7Da4n07MhDWt/vC4f5QeNwYKi1m0ncnPUh3/7NV5c+CdcGZJQfrldI/MNY+VIRJzt0PtyBRsn3u3xmtP/KjPC+gyGHuAh5jeY6u1dKsm0Oub6oDsBg46J7WXLul5xCuScdT7WR2RRjYE9PAp7KyXgoOYsIrNTgJH0Q0WbeVHwGbidqSZjp/GymyDdciW7+c1aBbyaA2fbB1O1kAGi+Ko8cpHPM9LmApqGvn2mvV2bdpHbFH8QYEXvTMxUHEPyA6MQ0LYFRXL1mu4yIFFaaQQ80Lb2wdv6jke1WIoXWYagnH7RIQ3lRRjgcWQlUAHkM2YjrJKN77f08A5/nP/pcbGZYRrfVnfp9S+St/R9uUVJK3dmoEW1SRVctwGZmlz4UgMn2aLZH+JxAU7WL25L3mwuMkUcLF4uLDOaelYEJnzBAXcAEAAQA= pcmagas@unknown]
WARNING: cannnot unmap ptr 0x7f9ced403000 as it is in the protected range from 0x7f9ced403000 to 0x7f9d6d603000
WARNING: cannnot unmap ptr 0x7f9d6d601000 as it is in the protected range from 0x7f9ced403000 to 0x7f9d6d603000
INFO    | Monitoring duration of emulator setup.
WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
INFO    | Using security allow list from: /home/pcmagas/Android/emulator/lib/emulator_access.json
WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
INFO    | The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: /run/user/1000/avd/running/77641/jwks/b6206e94-a6c8-4fb0-9c0b-1622ab1dbd73/active.jwk
INFO    | Scanning /run/user/1000/avd/running/77641/jwks/b6206e94-a6c8-4fb0-9c0b-1622ab1dbd73 for jwk keys.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_77641.ini
I0620 21:37:24.292412   77712 FrameBuffer.cpp:2853] setDisplayConfigs w 320 h 640 dpiX 160 dpiY 160
I0620 21:37:24.292439   77712 FrameBuffer.cpp:2866] setDisplayActiveConfig 0
INFO    | Loading snapshot 'default_boot'...
WARNING | Device 'cache' does not have the requested snapshot 'default_boot'
WARNING | Failed to load snapshot 'default_boot'
INFO    | Activated packet streamer for bluetooth emulation


And I have no idea how I can debug this or find the error why. Can you help me?
